# Rank of a set, could you give me an example?

Tags: set-theory, foundations

I don't understand the definition of rank of a set.
The definition I have is:

For any set $V_{\infty}$, the rank of $x$, written $\rho(x)$, is the least ordinal $\alpha$ for which $x \in V_{\alpha^+}$

$V_{\infty}$ is the class of all sets which are in at least one of the $V_{\alpha}$s. I've found here https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cumulative+hierarchy a few examples, and in particular that the rank of $\{1\}$ is $2$, but how? $\rho(\{1\})$=$\rho(\{\{\emptyset\}\})$, and its not true that $2=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ is the least ordinal for which $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \in V_{2^+}=V_3=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ what am i missing?

Comment: Please don't use $\alpha^+$ to denote the successor *ordinal* of $\alpha$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Why not? As I said 2000 times already (unfortunately) I'm reading this book https://www.amazon.com/Classic-Set-Theory-Independent-Mathematics-ebook/dp/B075FCTRKP and it calls $\alpha^+$ that's why I called it that way

Comment: @AndreaBurgio $α^+$ is how we denote that *cardinal* successor, $α+1$ is how we usually say *ordinal* successor, for infinite ordinals, this is very important to distinguish between them and to be clear about which one you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{\{∅\}\}∉V_0=∅$

$\{\{∅\}\}∉V_1=\{∅\}$

$\{\{∅\}\}∉V_2=\{∅,\{∅\}\}$

$\{\{∅\}\}∈V_3=\{∅,\{∅\},\{\{∅\}\},\{∅,\{∅\}\}\}$

So, the first stage where $\{1\}$ appear is $3=2+1$, so the rank of $\{1\}$ is $2$

Comment: Oh yeah you're right! I was thinking about the $V_\alpha$ as the normal natural numbers since the first three, from 0 to 2, have the same form, and i forgot that the successor is the powerset of the one that comes before. Thank you!